# exporting the environment variables to a csv in R

Tags: r, variables, export-to-csv

I am a newbie to R, so this question may seem trivial but how do you save enviroment variables to a table in R?

Let me give an example, below are the four variables I have calculated

```
number_of_loans_complete <- NROW(loans)
total_loan_sanctioned <- sum(loans$Sanctioned.Amount)
total_loan_proposed <- sum(loans$Requested.Amount)
average_tat_days <- mean(loans$Total.TAT, na.rm=TRUE)
```

I want to save them into a data.frame or table such that the output looks like

```
Name                            Value
number_of_loans_complete        13000 (calculated value)
total_loan_sanctioned           10000000000 (calculated value)
total_loan_proposed             11000000000
average_tat_days                4.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick solution:

```
write.csv(rbind(number_of_loans_complete, total_loan_sanctioned
      , total_loan_proposed, average_tat_days), file = "test.csv", row.names = T)
```

And the trick to export with colnames:

```
Names <- "Value"

write.table(rbind(Names
              , number_of_loans_complete = paste(number_of_loans_complete, "(calculated value)")
              , total_loan_sanctioned = paste(total_loan_sanctioned, "(calculated value)")
      , total_loan_proposed, average_tat_days), file = "test.csv", row.names = T
      , col.names = FALSE, sep = ",")
```

And if you want to save it into a data.frame in 2 steps you get:

```
df0 <- rbind(number_of_loans_complete, total_loan_sanctioned
      , total_loan_proposed, average_tat_days)

df <- data.frame("Names" = rownames(df0), "Value" = df0[,1], row.names = NULL)
```

So you can do any manipulations on `df` and then export

Comment: If this needs to be saved as a data.frame, then what does the code look like?

Comment: Thanks so much, you are awesome!